# Rails - Postgres - pluck attributes before they have been typecasted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, casting

Is there anything similar to:

```
Model.pluck(:id, :created_at_before_type_cast) # this does not work :)
```

Because when I do:

```
Model.pluck(:id, :created_at)
```

I get:

```
[1, 22 Feb 2018 13:15:33 CET +01:00]
...
```

but I need something like:

```
[1, 2018-02-22 12:15:33.426734]
...
```

Comment: What's wrong with calling `.to_s(:db)` on your datetime value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Model.pluck(:id, 'models.created_at AS created_at_before_type_cast')
```

seems to works